# React: Return last child object from nested props

Tags: javascript, object, reactjs

I have a *key-pair object* in an *object* within an *object* within an *object*.
I Object.assign the middle layer so the new object is an object within an object.

I send this new object as a prop.

I can console.log the new parent and child and see the object, but trying to console.log the last child returns

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'child' of undefined.

Wagwan?

```
obj:
    {
    Something: Null,
    Grandparent: {
        SomethinElse: Null,
        Parent: {
            SomethingMore: Null,
            Child: {
                SomeValue: "Duck"
            }
        }
    }

newObj:
    Child: {
        SomeValue: "Duck"
    }
```

Then I set

```
this.state.cow: newObj
```

Then I send to a component and call

```
{console.log(this.props.cow)}
```

> Object: {SomeValue: "Duck"}

good. Then I either log or render

```
{console.log(this.props.cow.SomeValue)}
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SomeValue' of undefined

Many thanks for your understanding in this rather basic question.

```js
export default class AwsReadFunction extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      main: {},
      info: {},
      cows: {}
   };
  } //constructor END

  componentDidMount() {
    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
    var table = "Movies";
    var year = 1944;
    var title = "Lifeboat";
    var params = {
      TableName: table,
      Key:{
        "year": year,
        "title": title
      }
    };

    docClient.get(params, (err, data) => {
      if(err){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
      } else {
        var ca = Object.assign({}, data.Item.info.cows);
        this.setState({
          main: data.Item,
          info: null,
          cows: ca
        });
      }
    });

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <List main={this.state.main} cows={this.state.cows} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default class List extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
      List cows-fish: {this.props.cows.fish} <br />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code where you do this operations you explained, as of right now, it is imposible to tell where the error is.

Comment: This kind of store will kill you in the future..

Comment: why are you not using **Redux**?

Comment: A) will load code when home,  b) loading a nested db object with the eventual plan to c) use redux, but want to learn more about react first

Comment: show some of your code

Comment: Some code ^ Thanks chaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the logic behind your code. If I were to bet money, I would guess it is a typo somewhere. These are a few inconsistencies I noticed:

- In your example object, `Child` has a capital C while in the error message it is lowercase
- You seem to be missing a closing curly brace in `AwsReadFunction`, right before the `render` method declaration.
- You use `cow` in a few places, then `cows` in other

This is obviously just a guess, but it won't hurt to double check :)

Comment: You know what, I'm slightly ashamed. It wasn't the code. My watchify stopped updating. I restarted the service and bam. It works.  I'm going to accept your answer because it made me look at the basics again. Thanks.